# C# Regular Expression to find annotations

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I am removing strings like [5] [12] the two brackets with a number between usign C#. I was wondering what the C# Regular expression to use while doing it. I have tried the following:

```
@"\[[0-9]{1,4}\]"
```

I thought this would work but it hasn't any help?

Comment: That looks right and works (according to [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)), the problem is probably in the rest of your code.

Comment: This helped me a lot with C# regex: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely It should work I tested out the following

```
        string str = "John[1234]is [2]a foo[944]l";
        string o = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[[0-9]+\]","");
        Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the regular expression tool @ http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html, your reg ex is good. But I think you need to remove the "@" since you are using the "\" escape character as an escape character.

I have just written and tested the following code, and it works just fine (on my machine :) )

```
     private static void RegexRemoveBracketedNumbers()
            {
                string testIt = @"\[[0-9]{1,4}\]";
                Console.WriteLine(testIt);
   // sure enough @Talljoe is right, this output as 
   //  \[[0-9]{1,4}\] without the @ it is an unrecognized escape sequence.. 
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[[0-9]{1,4}\]", RegexOptions.Singleline);
                string output = regex.Replace("[1] hello [2] world [a] how are you? [1234]", string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(output);
    // output = "hello world [a] how are you?"
    // as expected.
            }
```

when run from a console app...

Comment: No, he needs the @ _because_ he uses the '\' character (it's an escape character for the Regex, not C#).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string test = "strings like [5] [12]";
Regex getBrackettedText = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\[\d+\] \[\d+\]");
string[] values = getBrackettedText.Match(test).Value.Split();

Regex getNumber = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\d+");

foreach(string value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(getNumber.Match(value).Value));
}
```